# SQL subcategory total is not properly placed at the end of every parent category

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am having trouble in SQl query,The query result should be like this

```
+------------+------------+-----+------+-------+--+--+--+
|  District  |   Tehsil   | yes |  no  | Total |  |  |  |
+------------+------------+-----+------+-------+--+--+--+
| ABBOTTABAD | ABBOTTABAD | 377 | 5927 |  6304 |  |  |  |
| ABBOTTABAD | HAVELIAN   | 112 | 2276 |  2388 |  |  |  |
| ABBOTTABAD | Overall    | 489 | 8203 |  8692 |  |  |  |
| CHARSADDA  | CHARSADDA  | 289 | 3762 |  4051 |  |  |  |
| CHARSADDA  | SHABQADAR  | 121 | 1376 |  1497 |  |  |  |
| CHARSADDA  | TANGI      |  94 | 1703 |  1797 |  |  |  |
| CHARSADDA  | Overall    | 504 | 6841 |  7345 |  |  |  |
+------------+------------+-----+------+-------+--+--+--+
```

The `overall` total should be should be shown at the end of every parent category but now it is showing like this

```
+------------+------------+-----+------+-------+--+--+--+
|  District  |   Tehsil   | yes |  no  | Total |  |  |  |
+------------+------------+-----+------+-------+--+--+--+
| ABBOTTABAD | ABBOTTABAD | 377 | 5927 |  6304 |  |  |  |
| ABBOTTABAD | HAVELIAN   | 112 | 2276 |  2388 |  |  |  |
| ABBOTTABAD | Overall    | 489 | 8203 |  8692 |  |  |  |
| CHARSADDA  | CHARSADDA  | 289 | 3762 |  4051 |  |  |  |
| CHARSADDA  | Overall    | 504 | 6841 |  7345 |  |  |  |
| CHARSADDA  | SHABQADAR  | 121 | 1376 |  1497 |  |  |  |
| CHARSADDA  | TANGI      |  94 | 1703 |  1797 |  |  |  |
+------------+------------+-----+------+-------+--+--+--+
```

My query is sorting second column with respect to first column although order by query is applied on my first column. This is my query

```
select District as 'District', tName as 'tehsil',[1] as 'yes',[0] as 'no',ISNULL([1]+[0], 0) as "Total" from
(
select d.Name as 'District',
case when grouping (t.Name)=1 then 'Overall'  else t.Name end as tName,
BoundaryWallAvailable,
count(*) as total from School s 
INNER JOIN SchoolIndicator i ON (i.refSchoolID=s.SchoolID)
INNER JOIN Tehsil t ON (t.TehsilID=s.refTehsilID)
INNER JOIN district d ON (d.DistrictID=t.refDistrictID)
group by 
GROUPING sets((d.Name, BoundaryWallAvailable), (d.Name,t.Name, BoundaryWallAvailable))
) B
PIVOT
(
max(total)  for BoundaryWallAvailable in ([1],[0]) 
) as Pvt
order by District
```

P.S: `BoundaryWall` is one column through pivoting i am breaking it into `Yes` and `No` Column

Comment: Your results reflect the `ORDER BY` you have requested. If the order isn't what you want, that means you need to supply *more ordering criteria* in the `ORDER BY` clause. There is no assumed implicit ordering. You probably want a `CASE` expression to write a good expression in the `ORDER BY` the pushes `Overall` to the end.

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what i tried `order by case t.Name when 'Overall' then 1 else 2 end` but its giving error

Comment: After a `pivot`, all aliases swept up by the pivot aren't relevant. You probably want `Pvt.Name` rather than `t.Name`. But if you've tried something like this, you should include the attempt *and* the error in your quesion. BTW, you probably want `District,Case ...` rather than `Case ..., District` since `District` is the *major* ordering criteria.

Comment: And the default ordering is ascending. If you want `Overall` last, give it a *higher* value or do `DESC` ordering.

Comment: Sir you saved my day, this worked for me`order by  district,case Pvt.tName when 'Overall' then 2 else 1 end` placing district at the start rather than at the end did the trick for me